# how to search for a wildcard in array formula

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have got as far as the following array formula for trying to find timetable clashes at a school.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(E2:E8,MATCH(1,(F2:F8=F16)*(J16>=J2:J8)*(J16<K2:K8),0))))
```

- col `E` is the trip description
- col `F` is the Class form involved in the trip
- col `J` is the start/end time of the trip

it works fine, but now I need it to match any instance of `F16`s value within `F2:F8`.

This range lists the class forms which are on the trip and at the moment they  all need to be listed in their own separate cells for the match to work. I would prefer a solution where all the forms out for a trip could be listed in a single cell and the `arrayformula` would still find it.

Can I use a wildcard search for this? How can I use it for the match part?

Any help greatly appreciated,

steve

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH(1,(F2:F8=F16)*(J16>=J2:J8)*(J16<K2:K8),0)`
becomes:

`MATCH(1,(SEARCH(F16,F17)>0)*(J16>=J2:J8)*(J16<K2:K8),0)`

where F17 contains all the forms like so: Form1, Form2, Form3 etc.
Are you saying that all the forms would be in the one cell, and then if any form is =F16, then it still carries ot the other part.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Although it didn't work directly it definitely helped get to this

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Although it didn't work directly it definitely helped me get to =ArrayFormula(INDEX(E2:E8,MATCH(1,(J16>=J2:J8)*(J16<K2:K8)*(SEARCH("*"&F16&"*",F2:F8)>0),0))) which works. But strangely it only works one way. I want to be able to type a time&date (j16) and Form (F16) and for this array to check instances where all 3 conditions are met. This array works but if i delete the F16 cell it does not reset the array output to #N/A but rather holds the original value. If i delete either of the other 2 input cells they do reset the outcome. ?? any thoughts? thanks again for your help

Comment: Sorry, I've been very busy the last few days and not really looked at SO. The thing is that if the search term is "" - which is what an empty cell will be, then it will return that it is found. I'd check if the cell is blank first...

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I solved it by having it display 'Blank' if this cell was left empty as you suggested. Works fine now, thanks so much!